# Laravel 4 installation issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm having trouble getting Laravel 4 installed locally.  I am running this command:

`composer create-project laravel/laravel {directory} 4.2 --prefer-dist`

And I'm getting this error:  http://screencast.com/t/LYb4tg178C

Notice the file path is getting a permission denied:  `/Users/zenlightenstudios/.composer/cache/files/laravel/laravel/1713d69ca8ea2ea520f648d7f4a86d0f0a53f84f.zip`

However, I don't have a `.composer` folder in my user directory for `zenlightenstudios`.

Proof:  http://screencast.com/t/0h9bAM9EZ

**NOTE**: I have composer installed locally in my projects folder.

Any help on this is appreciated!

**UPDATE**

Looks like running `sudo` before my command fixed my issue.

Comment: Dot files and folders are not shown by default. The `~/.composer` folder probably exists.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like running `sudo` before my command fixed my issue.